# CodeIgniter and PHP 5.5.14 - mysql_escape_string() issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I've this issue after setting up CodeIgniter with PHP 5.5.14

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 320
```

It seems that mysql_real_escape_string() functions has been deprecated on 5.5.14, right?

CodeIgniter have no compatibility with this PHP version??

**Any ideas??**

Thanks in advance!

Giovanni

Comment: Refactor `mysql_escape_string()` to `mysql_real_escape_string()`, thats the idea. It should be only in `mysqli/mysqli_driver.php` file.

Comment: You should be using mysqli not mysql to avoid attacks.

Comment: use codeigniter built in function to escape queiries https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error with the MySQL configuration (I'm on a MacBook Pro). 
In practice, mysql's tmp path must be setup on mac.

After this step, my issue has disappeared!